# Inscribe circle in triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

In a triangle $ABC$ a point $I$  is a centre of inscribed circle. A line $AI$  meets a side $BC$  in a point $D$ . A bisector of $AD$  meets lines $BI$  and $CI$  respectively in a points $P$ and $Q$. Prove that heights of triangle $PQD$  meet in the point $I$.

I've tried to show that sides of triangle $PQD$  are parallel to sides of triangle $ABC$ but it didn't work out. That's why I ask you for help.

Comment: try something else then.

Comment: I've also tried to do it in cartesian coordiantes system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Diagram]

It suffices to show that $CI \perp PD$. Note that since $AP = PD$ and $BI$ is bisector of $\angle ABD$, point $P$ lies on the circumcircle of $\triangle ABD$ (on the midpoint of the arc). From this you can compute $\angle PDC = \angle IDC - \angle ADP = \angle IDC - \angle ABI$ and show it is $90^{\circ} - \frac12 \angle C$, which is all you need.

Comment: I think you meant $\angle IDC-\angle ABI$.

Comment: Yep -- fixed, thanks. :)

Comment: How to show that point $P$ lies on the circumcircle of the triangle $ABD$?

Comment: It's a standard lemma; see e.g. http://www.mit.edu/~evanchen/handouts/Fact5/Fact5.pdf

Comment: I went through it but this lemma assumes that point $P$ (in lemma point $L$) lies on the circumcircle of the triangle $ABD$ (in lemma $ABC$). In this task we want to prove that this point will lie on the circumcircle of the triangle $ABD$.

Comment: Since the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $AD$ and the bisector $BI$ is unique, we know it coincides with the point described in the lemma.